# Counting rows in a column combination with the same condition

Tags: python, dataframe, count, sum, pandas-groupby

What I am trying to do is a little complicated and I am struggling.
From these data, I want to get the counts of Y1, Y2 and Y3 that have both (Value A and Value C) equal to 1. Also both Value A and Value B =1.

```
Name |     Value A | Value B | Value C |

 Y1           1          0          0 
 Y1           1          0          0
 Y1           1          1          0 
 Y2           1          0          1
 Y2           0          1          0
 Y2           1          0          1
 Y3           1          0          0  
 Y3           1          1          0
 Y3           1          0          1
```

My desired output is:

```
Name   (Value A=1 and C=1)  (Value A=1 and B=1)
Y1         0                        1
Y2         2                        0
Y3         1                        1
```

I can only group them individually with "groupby" and "sum", and for all Values equal to 1. But I cannot make the combinations.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a boolean columns satisfying the conditions and `groupby` those columns and use `sum` to find the total counts:

```
out = (df.assign(A_C_eq_1=(df['Value_A'].eq(1) & df['Value_C'].eq(1)), 
                 A_B_eq_1=(df['Value_A'].eq(1) & df['Value_B'].eq(1)))
       .groupby('Name')[['A_C_eq_1', 'A_B_eq_1']]).sum().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  Name  A_C_eq_1  A_B_eq_1
0   Y1         0         1
1   Y2         2         0
2   Y3         1         1
```